# What does the kernel_regularizer parameter in a tf.keras.layers.Layer actually implement in terms of the loss function being optimized?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Consider the following model built using the `tf.keras` API where I used `kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2)` at the penultimate layer just before the sigmoid layer for binary classification.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),

    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'),
])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

What *exactly* does the `kernel_regularizer` parameter in a `tf.keras.layers.Layer` actually implement in terms of the loss function being optimized? Is this just adding the regularization penalty i.e.

[image]

to the loss function as is traditionally taught? Is it doing that with regards to all the network's weights or just that layer's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it just adds the regularization penalty to the loss with respect to that layer's weights, you can see that [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/regularizers.py#L37). This allows you to control which layers are regularized, you can even have different regularization strengths for each layer.

Comment: With respect to all the network's weights or just that layer's?

Comment: @fabiomaia See updated answer, it is for that layer's weight.